# How can I specify a particular user-agent string in a command-line invocation of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, terminal, user-agent

I would like to make a bash script that will iterate over different user agent options, open Firefox with the selected user agent, wait for x seconds, and then close, and loop.

Is there a command-line option for `firefox` to specify the user agent?

Comment: Posted code was completely irrelevant to the question.  Reworked question to focus on the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no flag for this specific purpose, but you can create a set of Firefox profiles, where each profile will specify a particular user agent.

There is an about:config option [`general.useragent.override`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries#General.), which you can specify in the `user.js` file in the profile folder with a line like:

```
user_pref("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/…")
```

You can then start Firefox with the [`-P`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-P_.22profile_name.22) flag, providing the name to the specific profile.

Comment: I had more luck with `general.useragent.override` . See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/98798/how-do-i-change-firefoxs-user-agent-via-aboutconfig) as well. Thanks!