# User agent not changing with firefox selenium getting setcapabilities issue

Tags: selenium, xpath

This code was working fine, but when switched to firefox from chrome now this is giving me error.

Please help me to find whats the solution

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.addArguments("--incognito");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
//        options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac\n" + "OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53");
        options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 6P Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxOptions(capabilities), options);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/abcd/Downloads/geckodriver");
        WebDriver driver = null;
```

Please help ....

Comment: `giving me error` what does the error says?

Comment: What is your Selenium version? Have you updated? Is `capabilities` actually defined?

Answer (score 0):

I can sense several issues:

- `driver.manage().window().maximize();`
- to browse incognito with Firefox use

  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

  options = Options()
     options.add_argument("-private")

  or see: [Python/Selenium incognito/private mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630190/python-selenium-incognito-private-mode)
- adjusting the user agent is more difficult: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42171906/8291949

  Basically, there is an about:config option general.useragent.override, which you can specify in the user.js file in the profile folder with a line like:

  ```
  user_pref("general.useragent.extra.firefox", "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36…")
  ```

  And than use capabilities to use the profile. Regarding capabilities see: [Can't open browser with Selenium after Firefox update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37761668/cant-open-browser-with-selenium-after-firefox-update)